# Creating a customer in BrainTree with a credit card

Tags: node.js, braintree

I'm reading the docs about creating a customer. I need to create one with a credit card, a cvc number but I get an error and I don't know how I must create it.

I show my code

```
if(user.local.subscription == undefined){
            //creamos cliente
            gateway.customer.create({
                creditCard : {
                    number : cardnumber,
                    expirationDate : "12/15"
                }
            }, function (err, result) {
                if(err){
                    //return res.status(500).json({ error : "Error creating customer"});
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(result);
                /*user.subscription = result;
                userId = result.customer.id;*/

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var braintree = require("braintree");

var gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "your sanboxmerchant",
  publicKey: "your sandbox public key",
  privateKey: "sandbox privatekey"
});

gateway.customer.create({
                creditCard : {
            cardholder_name : 'james bliz',
                    number : "4111111111111111",
            cvv : '123',
                    expirationDate : "12/17"
                }
            }, function (err, result) {
                if(err){
                    //return res.status(500).json({ error : "Error creating customer"});
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(result);
                /*user.subscription = result;
                userId = result.customer.id;*/

            });
```

the answer should be somthing like this

```
{ customer: 
   { id: '29931379',
     merchantId: 'qn5442rvm794nc6q',
     firstName: null,
     lastName: null,
     company: null,
     email: null,
     phone: null,
     fax: null,
     website: null,
     createdAt: '2015-05-12T10:33:41Z',
     updatedAt: '2015-05-12T10:33:42Z',
     customFields: '',
     creditCards: [ [Object] ],
     addresses: [],
     paymentMethods: [ [Object] ] },
  success: true }
```

take the required field from it i think you will need only the customer id from tha result object.